# Displaying Other Columns than Primary Key int asp MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I am trying to learn ASP.NET MVC 5 but I am stuck at the beginning :) I have simple database

- `dbo.Books` (int Id(PK), nvarchar(50) Title, int Author(foreignkey))
- `dbo.Author` (int ID(PK), nvarchar(50) Name)

And I am trying to display list of books using Entity Framework. My models looks like:

```
public class Author
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string  Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Book> Books { get; set; }
}

public class MovieContext :DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Books> Books{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Author { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Author")]
    public virtual Author Authorr { get; set; }
}
```

and when I go to `BooksController/index` it shows a list of books but instead of Name of Author it shows ID. I tried to change code

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Author)
```

for this:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Authorr.Name)
```

in the Index.cshtml class

But right now I am getting an error:

> Invalid object name dbo.Authors.

My table is called `Author` and I don't know why it is looking for `Authors` instead.

What should I change to display normal Name instead of Id of the `Author`?

Answer (score 0):

Change your forign key column to AuthorId and change the forign key navigational property from `Authorr` to `Author`

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }        
    public virtual Author Author { get; set; }
}
```

Now in your view you can do

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Author.Name)
```

Also when you get the data, you may use the `Include` method to load the author data.

```
var books = yourDbContext.Books.Include("Author").ToList();
return View(books);
```

Comment: i did like u said but it didnt solve the problem. EF is still looking for Authors table instead of Author

Comment: Did you rebuild your db with these changes ? I don't see any reason for this to fail

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code and it totally worked fine for me. The only change is `public DbSet<Book> Books{ get; set; }` not `public DbSet<Books> Books{ get; set; }`

Comment: Yep i did it, but it didnt help anyway

Comment: I solved the problem by changing TableName in MSSQL. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Total 4 Issues are there.

1 issue is here :

```
dbo.Books (int Id(PK), 
nvarchar(50) Title, 
int Author(foreignkey) //Wrong)
```

It should be

```
  dbo.Books (int Id(PK), 
    nvarchar(50) Title, 
    int AuthorId)
```

1 issue is here :

```
dbo.Author //Wrong
(int ID(PK), nvarchar(50) Name)
```

It should be

```
dbo.Authors (int ID(PK), nvarchar(50) Name)
```

2 issue are here :

```
 public class Book
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Author { get; set; } //Wrong
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Author")]
        public virtual Author Authorr { get; set; } //Wrong
    }
```

You should change it as shown below.

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Author")]
    public virtual Author Author { get; set; } 
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
}
```

I highly recommend you to follow [**Getting Started with ASP.NET MVC 5**](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started) article series to learn *ASP.net MVC 5*.

Comment: I changed it like u said but it didnt work. It is still trying to get data from Authors instead of Author Table

Comment: I am not using any specific tutorial. I was just looking for some informations about relationship between models in MVC and i was trying to create my own relationship

Comment: Don't you like to learn a Framework in proper way ? If you like,then you can follow the above mentioned series of articles.

Comment: Yep i solved the problem by changing name of table in MS SQL i know it is not the correct way but i have no idea how to solve it in other way. Thank you for your help. I added link, you posted few post above to favourites tab and i will start learning from it :) Thank you again

Comment: OK,Good Luck ! :)